# Org-capture displaying the calendar (how to do ?)

Tags: templates, emacs, org-mode

Can someone tell me if we can display the calendar in a org-capture template to pick up any date.  Using :

```
<%<%Y-%m-%d>>
```

pick the today date only .. :(

Thk

Answer (score 0):

I found this

```
%^t
```

will show-up the calendar to select a date + time